# What is parameter ?fbclid on Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, facebook, event-tracking, analytics-events

If I check my google anaytics I see this :

[image]

/xxxxxxxxxx-step is the number of people accessing this page

But I find /xxxxxxxxxx-step?fbclid=xxxxxxxxxx too. What is that? Is that the number of people who clicked the link to this page from Facebook?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a parameter Facebook adds to outbound links. It's possible it could be useful, but we did not find it so. We use UTM parameters on the links we put up on Facebook and get much more human-readable information that way, so we have been filtering `fbclid` out of our URLs since December.

If you wish to do the same, it's a quick edit: in Admin > [your view] > View Settings, put `fbclid` in the "Exclude URL Query Parameters" box and save.

[image]